# Spring MVC:How to get name of jsp file inside handler method

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a customer search function in spring mvc that calls the respective service classes upon a request.I want to design the handler method to be reusable,my problem is how do you return the view name based on the view from which the handler was called?The view name should be returned dynamically.Thank you.

```
View1
<form:form action="/search">
...
</form:form>

View2
<form:form action="/search">
...
</form:form>

Handler
@GetMapping("/search")
public String search(@RequestParam("searchTerm")String searchTerm,Model model){
   ...
   return View1 or View2;//How do you return view name dynamically based on from which view the request came
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by passing the view name from the view page to the handler method.
In all jsp view pages that require search functionality, I have the below code.

```
<%
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1,uri.lastIndexOf('.'));
  %>
<input type="hidden" name="pageName" value="<%= pageName%>">
```

And I had to retrieve the view name using `request.getParameter("pageName")` in the handler method.